# Error in train_object_detector.cpp dlib

Tags: c++, ubuntu, svm, dlib

I was trying to run train_object_detector.cpp in dlib library to train it for pedestrian detection. I'm using INRIA dataset and when i tried to use it, there was an exception:

```
exception thrown!
Error! An impossible set of object boxes was given for training. All 
the boxes 
need to have a similar aspect ratio and also not be smaller than about 
1600 
pixels in area. The following images contain invalid boxes: 
crop001002.png
crop001027.png
crop001038.png
crop001160.png
crop001612.png
crop001709.png
Try the -h option for more information.
```

when i removed these photos, it did run and loaded all photos but then another exception was thrown

```
exception thrown!
An impossible set of object labels was detected. This is happening 
because none
of the object locations checked by the supplied image scanner is a 
close enough
match to one of the truth boxes. To resolve this you need to either 
lower the 
match_eps or adjust the settings of the image scanner so that it hits 
this truth box. Or you could adjust the offending truth rectangle so 
it can be matched by the current image scanner. Also, if you are using 
the scan_image_pyramid object then you could try using a finer image 
pyramid or adding more detection templates. E.g. if one of your 
existing detection templates has a matching width/height ratio and 
smaller area than the offending rectangle then a finer image pyramid 
would probably help.
```

please help me to deal with that.

Answer (score 1):

Did you label your images using ImgLab?

When you label your images with this tool, keep in mind that your bounding boxes must have a similar aspect ration and that these bounding boxes must be smaller than the sliding window.
Usually, the example that you are running should dynamically calculate the size of the sliding window according to the provided boxes.

I'd suggest that you modify the source code a bit to do further tracking for the error source, if non of these helps.